# bot.get_channel() occasionally returning none in discord.py,

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to write a discord.py bot. The following is an abridgement of my full code.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix="!", sort_commands=False)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    channel = bot.get_channel(12345678912345678912)
    await channel.send("This is a test.")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Sometimes, the code above will work as intended, printing the connection message and sending  the desired message into the target channel.

This is not always the case, however! I am getting an issue where the `bot.get_channel()` command returns `none` instead of the correct data. I assume this means that the channel cannot be found, except for the fact that the channel does exist.

The error that is sent to the console is;
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

I am very, very new to discord.py so I would appreciate any help I can get to better understand what's going on under the hood here. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try using an `await` with `bot.get_channel`.

Comment: Doing `channel = await bot.get_channel` returns type error `object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression`

Comment: @MrDiamond `get_channel` isn't async...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer is not recommended.

The reason it doesn't work is because the cache isn't populated yet in `on_ready`, but **you should not make API requests** (`fetch_X` & `send`) **in `on_ready`**! Making API calls in there has a high chance for Discord to just disconnect your bot.

Also, `on_ready` gets triggered **multiple times**, so you'll end up sending this message constantly even though you only started it once.

There's rarely a reason to do anything at all in there. If you want something to run once on startup you can create a `Task` & start it in `setup_hook`.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do your method, nor can I find anything on the internet that uses this method. Would it be possible to provide some example code for me to understand how this works? Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Cutgrey there's examples in the dpy docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The `get_channel` method is a cache lookup method, so it's not always reliable, or the bot doesn't have access to the channel, and since it doesn't raise an exception if the cache wasn't found and returns `None` instead, you can't know the reason for sure. You can use [fetch_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_channel#discord.Client.fetch_channel) to make an API request after `get_channel` if it returns none; this method will raise an exception if the channel was not found or it doesn't have permission to fetch.

```py
channel = (bot.get_channel(1234567890) or await bot.fetch_channel(1234567890))
await channel.send("This is a test.")
```

Also it seems like you have both `discord.ext.commands.Bot` and `discord.Client` instance, please choose one and remove the other.

Comment: This seems to work well. I also deleted the discord.Client instance, but why can't I use both (if necessary, because it wasn't used in the sample code)? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Don't make API calls in `on_ready`.

Comment: @Cutgrey you can't use both because you can only run one at a time. `Bot` is a subclass of `Client`, so a Bot can do everything a Client can do. There's 0 reason to ever have both in your code.